# Turn turtlebot2 10 degrees about its axis

Tags: python-2.7, ros, robotics

How are you? How can I turn turtlebot2 10 degrees about its axis and then pause.
Note: The robot will not move, it will just rotate 10 degrees once every say 20 seconds.
I tried setting the Twist() object's angular velocity in the Z direction but only one wheel moves and ultimately the robot is displaced.

below is my code:

```
                angular_velocity = radians(10) #10 degs / s

                r = rospy.Rate(5) #5Hz
                #rospy.loginfo("starting loop")
                while not rospy.is_shutdown():
                        rospy.loginfo("in loop")
                        new_angle = (angle + new_angle) % 360
                        real_angle = real_angle + angle
                        #real_angle = rea1_angle + 5
                        rospy.loginfo("after addition")
                        new_angle =  real_angle % 360
                  
                        turn_cmd.angular.z = angular_velocity #turns 10 degrees a second
                        #turn at 10 degrees a second for 1 second  
                        for i in range(5):
                                self.cmd_vel.publish(turn_cmd)
                                r.sleep()
                        r.sleep()
    # wait 40s
                        for x in range(200):
                                self.cmd_vel.publish(Twist()) #publish ) to stop the bot at that point
                                # stop the turtle and gather data as u  wait
                                r.sleep()
                                try:
                                        data = "get some data from external source"
                                        if(data):
                                                try:
                                                        #rospy.loginfo("w(rads/$
                                                        comb_d.write( str(data)
                                                except:
                                                        rospy.loginfo("failed or bad data)
                                                        pass
                          r.sleep()
                          comb_d.close()


        def shutdown(self):
                # stop turtlebot
                rospy.loginfo("Stop turning")
                self.cmd_vel.publish(Twist())
```

The above is my logic. But not only does the robot move, it also does not turn 10 degrees as I expect.
What am i doing wrong?
Thank you very much.
Am using ROS indigo kobuki and turtlebot2

That being said - on slightly different note - what would be the favorable values for the `rospy.Rate()` function and the inner `for` loop to achieve the `10` or even `30` degree rotation at a relative higher angular velocity, say `25 degrees per second`. Because it seems the robot does not work well with low velocities such as `10 degs/s`. Some times it does not move at all when low velocities are given. Eitherway, thanks.

Comment: 5Hz is most likely to low of a rate. There may be a cmd_vel_mux running that ignores any cmd_vel publisher that doesn't send messages often enough. 10 deg/s also seems low. Also check whether any other node is publishing cmd_vel. For instance, if you have rviz open, it might be publishing 0 speeds. Run `rostopic info /cmd_vel` to see who's publishing.

Comment: @Christian Fritz thanks.  ok this makes sense. No one else is publish to `/cmd_vel_mux/active` but I certainly do publish zeros to it because I do want it to rotate, then pause for a significantly longer time than it spends rotating then rotate again. I updated the code to give u the whole picture. So whats a better/optimal configuration to have this? for example, what rate and angular speed, for how long could be optimal for me to achieve a 10 or even 30 degreee periodical turn? thank you. say i want to pause for about `30seconds or even 20seconds`, if it will give better results.

Comment: actually perhaps i dont need to publish a zero `Twist()` that many times. Let me try putting it just before the second `for loop`.